# How to prevent BrokenPipeErrors after receiving a SIGINT while using process shared objects in Python?

Tags: python, proxy, sigint, broken-pipe

This Python program:

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import time

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.event = multiprocessing.Manager().Event()

    def start(self):
        try:
            while True:
                if self.event.is_set():
                    break
                print("processing")
                time.sleep(1)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(type(e).__name__ + " (from pool thread):", e)

    def shutdown(self):
        self.event.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        a = A()
        pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
        future = pool.submit(a.start)
        while not future.done():
            concurrent.futures.wait([future], timeout=0.1)
    except BaseException as e:
        print(type(e).__name__ + " (from main thread):", e)
    finally:
        a.shutdown()
        pool.shutdown()
```

outputs:

```
processing
processing
processing
KeyboardInterrupt (from main thread):
BrokenPipeError (from pool thread): [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 788, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\foo.py", line 34, in <module>
    a.shutdown()
  File ".\foo.py", line 21, in shutdown
    self.event.set()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 1067, in set
    return self._callmethod('set')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 792, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 779, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 490, in Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 691, in PipeClient
    _winapi.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

when it is run and a `SIGINT` signal is sent after three seconds (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

*Analysis.* — The `SIGINT` signal is sent to the main thread of each process. In this case there are two processes: the main process and the manager's child process.

- In the main thread of the main process: after receiving the `SIGINT` signal, the default `SIGINT` signal handler raises the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, which is caught and printed.
- In the main thread of the manager's child process: in the mean time, after receiving the `SIGINT` signal, the default `SIGINT` signal handler raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, which terminates the child process. Consequently all subsequent uses of the manager's shared objects by other processes raise a `BrokenPipeError` exception.
- In the pool's child thread of the main process: in this case, a `BrokenPipeError` exception is raised at the line `if self.event.is_set():`.
- In the main thread of the main process: Finally, the flow of control reaches the line `a.shutdown()`, which raises the `AttributeError` and `FileNotFoundError` exceptions.

**How to prevent this `BrokenPipeError` exception?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this issue is to override the default `SIGINT` signal handler with a handler that will ignore the signal, for instance with the [`signal.SIG_IGN`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/signal.html#signal.SIG_IGN) standard signal handler. It is possible by calling the [`signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/signal.html#signal.signal) function at the start of the manager's child process:

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing.managers
import signal
import time

def init():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        manager = multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager()
        manager.start(init)
        self.event = manager.Event()

    def start(self):
        try:
            while True:
                if self.event.is_set():
                    break
                print("processing")
                time.sleep(1)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(type(e).__name__ + " (from pool thread):", e)

    def shutdown(self):
        self.event.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        a = A()
        pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
        future = pool.submit(a.start)
        while not future.done():
            concurrent.futures.wait([future], timeout=0.1)
    except BaseException as e:
        print(type(e).__name__ + " (from main thread):", e)
    finally:
        a.shutdown()
        pool.shutdown()
```

*Note.* — This program also works with a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.